# If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space, $V= \operatorname{span}(W)$ and $|W|=n$ then $W$ is a basis for $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space, $V= \operatorname{span}(W)$ and $W=\{w_1,...,w_n\}$ then $W$ is a basis for $V$.

Since $V= \operatorname{span}(W)$ in order to prove $W$ is a basis for $V$ the only thing left to prove is that $W$ is linearly independent, I decided to proceed by contradiction:

I supposed that $W$ is linearly dependent, so $\exists w_i \in W$ such that $w_i \in  \operatorname{span}(W\setminus \{w_i\})$, because $W$ spans $V$, then so does $W\setminus \{w_i\}$. Therefore, there exists a subset $S$ of $W\setminus \{w_i\}$ that is a basis for $V$ (I've already proved this property, so I can use it in good conscience).

Now, because $S \subset W\setminus \{w_i\}$ and $|W\setminus \{w_i\}|=n-1$, then $|S|\leq n-1$, then, because S is a basis for V, $\dim(V)\leq n-1$ and there's my contradiction.

I was just wondering if perhaps there's an easier way of proving this property, or if I made a mistake somewhere along the way.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: If you already know that any spanning set contains a basis, then just start by saying that $W$ contains a basis $S\subseteq W$. If $S$ is a *proper* subset, then $|S|\leq n-1$, which is a contradiction, so $S=W$.

Comment: Oh that's a very clever way of shortening the proof @ArturoMagidin, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer looks okay, but you took the long way round. A more direct argument is the following (same idea as Arturo's):

Since the generating set $W$ must contain a basis, and $W$ has $n$ elements, then $W$ already forms a basis, since all bases have the same cardinality $n$ (the dimension is defined precisely as the cardinality of any basis).

PS. A basis is not a mere set of vectors but rather an *ordered* sequence (or set). Order matters!